# From a list count occurences and create a new list with count added

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
list_a = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'hello', 'whatever', 'whatever', 'whatever', 'hello']
```

I would like to create a new list with item count like this:

```
list_b = ['hello_1', 'goodbye_1', 'goodbye_2', 'hello_2', 'whatever_1', 'whatever_2', 'whatever_3', 'hello_3']
```

I have tried things like this:

```
list_b=[]
for item in list_a:
    list_b.append(item+"_"+str(list_a.count(item)))
```

But this will of course add total Count of each element.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: This is no free coding service.

Comment: use a dict to keep track of current word count while iterating through your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Python's [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) to count each word as you go along:

```
from collections import Counter

word_count = Counter()
list_a = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'hello', 'whatever', 'whatever', 'whatever', 'hello']
list_b = []

for word in list_a:
    word_count[word] += 1
    list_b.append('{}_{}'.format(word, word_count[word]))

print list_b
```

Giving you:

```
['hello_1', 'goodbye_1', 'goodbye_2', 'hello_2', 'whatever_1', 'whatever_2', 'whatever_3', 'hello_3']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dict to store the index:

```
list_a = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'hello', 'whatever', 'whatever', 'whatever', 'hello']

d={}
r=[]
for i in list_a:
    d.setdefault(i, 0)
    d[i]+=1
    r.append(i+"_"+str(d[i]))

print r
```

Output:

```
['hello_1', 'goodbye_1', 'goodbye_2', 'hello_2', 'whatever_1', 'whatever_2', 'whatever_3', 'hello_3']
```

Another Pythonic way:

```
>>> list_a = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'hello', 'whatever', 'whatever', 'whatever', 'hello']
>>> d={}
>>> [i+"_"+str(len(d[i])) for i in list_a if not d.setdefault(i,[]).append(True)]
['hello_1', 'goodbye_1', 'goodbye_2', 'hello_2', 'whatever_1', 'whatever_2', 'whatever_3', 'hello_3']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `enumerate`,

```
[j+'_'+str(list_a[:i+1].count(j)) for i,j in enumerate(list_a)]
```

**Idea:**

> using `enumerate` i will get the index of element as well, So will
>   slice up to the current element and will count the no.of occurance in
>   the sliced list.

**Result:**

```
['hello_1', 'goodbye_1', 'goodbye_2', 'hello_2', 'whatever_1', 'whatever_2', 'whatever_3', 'hello_3']
```

**Execution time:**

As per the discussion in my answer's comments about the execution timings, i have gone through the all the method implemented here, Here are the timings,

```
In [68]: %timeit Mc_grady_method_1()
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.29 µs per loop

In [69]: %timeit Mc_grady_method_2()
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.35 µs per loop

In [70]: %timeit Rahul_KP()
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.8 µs per loop

In [71]: %timeit Moe_A()
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.94 µs per loop

In [72]: %timeit Allen()
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.1 µs per loop

In [73]: %timeit Mayur_Buragohain()
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.86 µs per loop

In [74]: %timeit Martin_Evans()
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.5 µs per loop
```

Still my method make a slight good performance among this.

Comment: Quite a clever way of doing this.

Comment: @Julien Updated my question please check it.

Comment: Testing on a toy list with 3 elements isn't going to show the massive hit you take between a O(n) and a O(n^2) method, try again on a 1,000,000 item list and I bet your method will be slow compared to a good O(n) one (unless Python does some sneaky memoization for you under the hood...)

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

list_a = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'hello', 'whatever', 'whatever', 'whatever', 'hello']

#build a counter for each word and a index list for each word.
counter = {k:list(range(v+1,0,-1)) for k,v in collections.Counter(list_a).items()}

#attach index to each each occurance of a word
list_b = [e+'_'+str(counter[e].pop()) for e in list_a]
print(list_b)

['hello_1', 'goodbye_1', 'goodbye_2', 'hello_2', 'whatever_1', 'whatever_2', 'whatever_3', 'hello_3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this-

```
list_a = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'hello', 'whatever', 'whatever', 'whatever', 'hello']
list_b=[]
someDict={}
for item in list_a:
    if item in someDict.keys():
        temp_count=someDict[item]+1
        temp_item=list_b.append(item+"_"+str(temp_count))
        someDict[item]=temp_count
    else:
        list_b.append(item+"_1")
        someDict[item]=1
print list_b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temp `list` to add the word and then add it to list_b with the count like:

```
list_a = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'hello', 'whatever', 'whatever', 'whatever', 'hello']
    list_b = []
    tmp = []
    for word in list_a:
        tmp.append(word)
        list_b.append(word + '_' + str(tmp.count(word)))
    print list_b
```

output:

```
['hello_1', 'goodbye_1', 'goodbye_2', 'hello_2', 'whatever_1', 'whatever_2', 'whatever_3', 'hello_3']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know which elements you will get in your list, you can create a variable for counting them. You can even do it with two loops :

The code provided is not the smartest way to do it, but it should work well

```
list_items=[]
counters_items=[]
for item in list_a:
    if item in list_items:
        pass
    else:
        list_items.append(item)

# Now we have stored a list of all type of item

list_b = list_a.copy()
for item in list_items:
    counter = 1
    for it in list_b:
        if item == it:
            it = it + "_" + str(counter)
            counter +=1
    # If you want to make sure the whole list has been numbered
    if counter != list_a.count(item) + 1:
        print "Smth wrong happened"
```